# /index.xhtml @11,63 value="#{user.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'user' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, el, propertynotfoundexception

I keep getting error code (as seen in the images attached):

> /index.xhtml @11,63 value="#{user.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'user' resolved to null

[image]

Also I have attached my managed bean and index.xhtml

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't add code in images

Comment: sorry for putting the code in images, I'm new to all this, next time i'd put the code as code. @JasperdeVries

Comment: That did not solve my problem, but i have solved it and i would be putting the solution out very soon